# Aumentar la vista del diseñador de Windows Forms en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Windows Forms en Visual Studio 2022 y quiero pode hacerle zoom para poder visualizar correctamente ciertas distancias entre controles.

Comment: Y cual es el problema??? usa el zoom...

Comment: si te refieres al zoom de windows como tal no me resulta porque se ve muy borroso

Comment: visual studio tiene zoom propio sobre los forms... no lo encuentras?

Comment: no...como lo consigo?

Comment: abajo a la derecha hay un zoom... o que estas mirando??? tambien deberias verlo en el menu editar.. y tambien deberias poder hacer zoom con ctrl+ruedita del mouse...

Comment: estoy buscado hacer eso en el diseñador de Windows Forms, aqui no hay zoom debajo y pensé que se podría hacer con la tecla ctrl+Scroll pero no se puede, o al menos no tengo eso habilitado, ahora cuando estoy en el código si puedo hacerlo a voluntad, pero en el diseñador no...

Comment: Tenes razon. Por algun motivo, en vs 2022 para winforms no esta mas... y no logro encontrar como hacer zoom...

Comment: por eso, quiero ver que solucion puedo encontrar